# run Libreoffice 4 headless at startup

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

i used 
http://www.openvpms.org/documentation/install-openoffice-headless-service-ubuntu

for run openoffice and libreoffice 3 at ubuntu start up

but

due to some PID change it dont work for liberoffice4

anybody know how can i run Libreoffice 4 at startup!?

UPDATE 1 : as its mentioned in the link I mean libreoffice - headless in ubuntu server so it dont have any UI.

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice, this is called Quickstart, and is enabled on this tab: Tools/Options/LibreOffice/General. It may tell you that the Quickstart module needs to be installed for this, but as far as I'm aware, that is installed automatically.

Comment: Thank you , i updated my question for a better view.as i updated i have to run in start-up in a server environment so it havnt ui..

Comment: There is the --headless option. Does that do what you want?

Comment: i installed the server version of the libreoffice as well and its working good but it dont start after server reboot,i just need an auto start of the Libreoffice and server boot